# trying to learn the syntax and structure of cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, function, class

I'm trying to write a cakephp app. I need to validate input based on availability. an example would be if someone is trying to take out a book from a library. I would reference the book to see if it's currently out, and if it is report that to the user.

another example would be trying to book rooms at a hotel, the user would enter a date and a length of their visit, and the function would check to see if that room is available for that length of time.

I'm writing this in the controller, but I'm confused about how to a) grab the data I need from the database, and b) how to pass that data between functions. I know how I would do this using php/mysql but I'm not familiar with cakephp and I can't find a tutorial that just goes over the basics.

edit: i think i got it down, i'll update in a bit.

Comment: Have you gone through the tutorials? They do explain key concepts and architecture of CakePHP pretty well.

Comment: yes i have, but i found them lacking detail. do you know of any other tutorials that go more in depth with an example project? similar to the cakephp blog but one that includes comments and marking your post with tags?

Comment: There are many different implementation to that. I found it really hard to find one perfect tutorial or way of doing things in CakePHP. I've been relying on trying different stuffs by going through the manual (http://book.cakephp.org/) or the google group (http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php?pli=1). I would look into Models (http://book.cakephp.org/view/66/Models) for retrieving data from db and look more into controllers and components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/view/219/Blog) on the CakePHP website. That's where I started. It guides you through all the steps, including Data Validation.

Read the rest of the [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/) as you start writing your own application.

Comment: I did look through that, but it mostly refers to grabbing unconstrained data from a single table.

it was somewhat helpful, but i found it lacking since it really didn't touch on the subject of associated data. like if it were to show comments on a post, and if it showed how to limit results so it only showed posts from a certain time frame.

thank you for the post though.

Comment: I have all my associations setup already. I tested them using scaffolding and every table seemed to be linked properly to each other. now i need to write my own code for this application. so i made a few controller functions, they really just passed data to the view which worked fine. now I'm trying pull data from the database to use inside a function to generate a list that i can pass to a view. i can get the data from the model to the view using a controller but i am not sure how to use the data inside the controller.

Comment: Maybe an idea to store the data you retrieve from the db in $var, then use the function pr($var) to see what the data array you retrieved from the db looks like before you pass it to the view.

Comment: the cakephp documentation helped me find out what i needed to know, mostly that i needed to make components for the bits of code i was trying to write. i don't like documentation because i always find the examples lacking, and i still don't have working code, but i believe i am on the right track.